# How can I convert this working mysql statement to PDO effectively?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to convert to using PDO, but can't seem to get results from my PDO while loop.

This mysql statement gives me results:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY artist ASC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  $theartist .= '<option value="'.($row['artist_id']).'">'.($row['artist'])."</option>";
}
```

PDO database connection (that appears to work)

```
//the below isn't throwing any errors
$host='localhost';
$dbname='james_test';
$user='test';
$pass='testpass';

try {
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This PDO statement does not give me any results:

```
$query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY artist ASC");
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $theartist .= '<option value="'.($row['artist_id']).'">'.($row['artist'])."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Add `$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. You also need to `execute()`. Always read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php before getting into the driver's seat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just makes it work by slightly changing your code.

```
//$query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY artist ASC");
$rows = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY artist ASC");

//while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
if ($rows) {
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $theartist .= ''.($row['artist'])."";
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
The query function does both prepare and execute in one go and is useful if you don't have variables to use in the query.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I'm guessing that $rows was empty. I think your will need to check if $rows has something. I'll make a change to my code.

Comment: if($rows) doesn't throw an error, but there is still no results.

Comment: Do a var_dump on $rows before the if statement and see if $rows has anything. **var_dump($rows)**.

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=&gt;
  string(40) "SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY artist ASC"
}

Comment: I actually missed a step, this works if I change prepare to query.  It must not need to be prepared or executed if you aren't using placeholders/variables.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes. **According to the PHP documentation, query will do both those steps in one go. [http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)**. I was able to use the $rows as an array though in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the step where you run the query. With a PDO, you can prepare the query which optimises performance and helps prevent SQL injection, but you must still "execute" the statement.

```
$query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist ORDER BY artist ASC");
$result = $query->execute();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $theartist .= '<option value="'.($row['artist_id']).'">'.($row['artist'])."</option>";
}
```

Related PHP manual entries:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I copied and pasted it but my page doesn't load properly if i change the code this way.